# Batch File Delete

Tags: batch-file

We are having issues with a couple of files on our network. These files are -

```
dataserv.lg 
xmlemail.tmp 
socketemail.log
```

As we use Citrix these files get created within the users unique profile.

As an example they get written to -

```
\\Mhsvi-xenprof\e$\XenProfiles\user1\UPM_Profile
\\Mhsvi-xenprof\e$\XenProfiles\user2\UPM_Profile
```

I need a batch file that will go through the "XenProfiles" folder and go through each "user" folder in turn and then in the "UPM_Profile" folder in order to search and delete the three offending files.

Not really sure where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. At first sight it doesn't seem too much of a challenge. You should start by writing this batch file, then come back here if you get stuck.  Please have a look at the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have no experience at all at writing batch files so like I said I wouldn't know where to start. We do have the following script that does something similar -

Comment: Sorry it won't let me post it as it's too large.

Comment: Unfortunately we're not a code writing community nor a technology training one. Your starting point if you want to get help on SO would be to learn the basics and try to use it to accomplish what you want (which is as I said, fairly basic too). The once you've got some code showing some efforts, SO community can definitely help. Of course you may find someone kind enough to do it for you, but that wouldn't make you better in writing batch files...

Comment: The del command is recursive. To delete a.txt and b.txt anywhere on a harddrive. `del c:\a.txt c:\b.txt /s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should delete those three files anywhere in all user profiles.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (dataserv.lg xmlemail.tmp socketemail.log) do del "\\Mhsvi-xenprof\e$\XenProfiles\%%a" /s
```